# js/iframes: force iframes to reload

Tags: html, iframe, javascript

How can I force an iframe to reload and not load from cache?

Answer (score 4):

To force it to reload *every time*, add a random GET parameter to its URL:

```
iframe.src = "testpage.html?reload="+Math.random();#
```

or as Jacob suggests, the current timestamp (eliminating the possibility of duplicates):

```
iframe.src = "testpage.html?reload="+(new Date()).getTime();
```

Comment: Better yet, `iframe.src = "testpage.html?reload="+(new Date()).getTime();`  Because you COULD get the same random number back ;)

Comment: @acewundabar If you want a more detailed explanation, you will need to show the code you currently use to embed the iframe, and maybe explain some more about your situation.

Comment: @acewundabar you can edit your question and add the information, by the way.

Comment: <iframe src="path.html"></iframe>

Comment: @acewundabar Please explain what your situation is and what you want to do. I'm not going to explain all 1500 ways of giving an iframe a new src.

Comment: I want it to reload everytime the page loads?  I don't understand... I want to use your code.

Comment: @acewundabar I'm sorry I can't help you with this right now, I need to leave for the day. Maybe someone else will pick up the thread. What you need to do is, you need to build a JavaScript that assigns the iframe's `src` when the document loads. This can't be done using simple HTML I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

```
someIframe.src += "#forceReload";
```

Should work. or:

```
someIframe.src += "?fakeQuery";
```